# Calling a function at a AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with AngularJS.

I have a working sample as this :

http://jsfiddle.net/IgorMinar/Hxbqd/5/

And I would like to modify it to directly call at my `connectControl` function as this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hxbqd/68/

The only slight change between them is:

```
$scope.registerWithFacebook();
```

Why is not this one working? Or What I have to do make it work?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by it is not working

Comment: That might be a problem with the service, that calls the $apply function while you are already in a digest cycle. I am not an expert, but had a similar problem when calling $apply in response to something different than a DOM event.

Comment: do you have any error in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arun P Johny suggested there was error in my console.

The problem is that FB was not ready at changed statement. When I replaced it something like this

```
setTimeout(function(){$scope.registerWithFacebook()},3000);
```

It started to work.